# Google Sheets - Can I manually overwrite importrange and query functions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, copy-paste

I am currently using importrange and query functions to bring in data across cells in a Google Sheet. When I try to manually change a cell, I get the error that says the whole query or import range could not be expanded because it would overwrite my manual edit. What I want is to have the query or importrange bring in information but also be able to change individual cells if needed and I have not been able to find any documentation how/if this is possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible. you either have an active formula or editable data. to transit from active formula into an editable dataset you can use <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd></kbd> > <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd></kbd> > <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd></kbd> to overwrite your formula